# Relation between dimension and codimension in infinite dimensional dual vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an infinite dimensional vector space and $V^*$ its dual space. Let $W$ a subspace of $V^*$.Is it always true that $\mathrm{codim}(\mathrm{annihilator}(W)) \leq \dim W$ ?

Please give a proof or a counterexample. If $W$ is finite dimensional I have a proof, I think.
With annihilator $W$ I mean all v in $V$ such that $f(v)=0$ for all $f$ in $W$.
Please help me.